# Change Programmatic Access in Excel via VBA code in registry

Tags: excel, vba

I want to try to load updates of my modules into an Excel workbook every time it is started and there where changes made in the module on the server.

I do not want the "Developer Macro Settings - Trust Access to the VBA project object model" to stay "active" for every user. My goal is to activate it before I load the new modules and deactivate it afterwards. I tried it via the registry and the checkbox is checked afterwards but I do not have access to the Object Model. After a restart of Excel the checkbox is unchecked so it seems that I did not set the right registry entry.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Excel\Security\AccessVBOM
```

This is the regkey I set via

```
WshShell.RegWrite "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Excel\Security\AccessVBOM", 1, "REG_DWORD"
```

I know there could be

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Excel\Security\AccessVBOM
```

as well, but this does not seem to be in this case.

Comment: Seems like MS anticipated this.  When Excel starts it reads the key from the registry, and always uses this value.  When Excel closes it writes the stored value back to the registry, overwriting your change.

Comment: One workaround would be to place your code in an add-in and load it from the server when the workbook opens.  It's a bit more complex but still easier than trying to live-update the code in the workbook.

Comment: I've seen a workaround for this somewhere,  can't find it atm. IIRC it involved involves writing a script to change the registry setting with Excel closed.  Can be orchestrated from within Vba: basically 1. Generate the script 2. Schedule the script to run soon 3. Exit Excel.  In the script  1. Change registry 2. Start Excel

Comment: Yup, I tend to use self-destructing VBScript files for things like that. You can start the script directly, poll every few seconds if Excel is still open (using `GetObject`), and if it isn't, make the modification to the registry. That avoids the mess with scheduling. Note that some antivirus software doesn't like self-destructing VBScript files that modify the registry.